# I want to edit record then update it using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, insert-update

I am trying to edit record when I click Edit Button record is not fetching into input field using laravel

Does anyone have any idea How can I fix it?
  I am facing an error

> Property [product_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/sigmadel/public_html/resources/views/admin/product_update.blade.php)

**Controller**

```
public function update_projects($products_id){
    $category=DB::table('category')->get();
    $projects=DB::table('projects')->where('products_id','=',$products_id)->get();
    return view('admin/product_update',compact('category','projects'));
}
```

**html view**

```
<form   action="{{route('product.action')}}"   method="post"    >
    @csrf
    <div class="group-form">
        <select  class="form-control">
            <option > Update Category</option>
            @foreach($category as $categories)
            <option value="">{{$categories->category_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$projects->product_name}}"
               placeholder="Update Product Name" name="product_name" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="select_file" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" value="UPDATE"  name="Update" >
    </div>
</form>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('product.update',$projects->products_id)}}">Edit</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('view_projects','AdminController@view_projects');
Route::get('product_update/{products_id}/edit','AdminController@update_projects')->name('product.update');
```

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: Actully When i click edit button record should be Shown into input field on update page

Comment: I am facing this error


Property [product_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/sigmadel/public_html/resources/views/admin/product_update.blade.php)

Comment: As the error suggest product_name does not exist. Check your results whether this property exists or not. You can check it using dd() method.

Comment: share your model and table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong all along. you are getting collection as you are using `get()` but trying to use it as object. do it this way.

route:

```
Route::get('project_edit/{id}/edit','AdminController@edit_project')- 
     >name('project.edit');
Route::post('project_update/{id}/update','AdminController@update_project')- 
     >name('project.update');
```

controller edit function:

```
public function edit_project($id){           
    $categories=DB::table('category')->get();
    $project=DB::table('projects')->where('products_id','=',$id)->first();
    return view('admin/product_update',compact('categories','project'));    
}
```

edit blade:

```
<form action="{{route('project.update', $project->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="group-form">
        <select  class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if($project->category_id) == $category->id) selected @endif>{{$category->category_name}}</option>       
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$project->product_name}}" 
             placeholder="Update Product Name" name="product_name" >  
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="select_file" >      
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" value="UPDATE"  name="Update" >  
    </div>
</form>
```

and finally the update function in controller:

```
public function update_project(Request $request, $id){           
    //validation and update process    
}
```

> here project and product got mixed badly so change it according to your structure.

Comment: After Applying your code   i am facing this error how to fix it ? record not showing on update page

Undefined property: stdClass::$porduct_name (View: /home/sigmadel/public_html/resources/views/admin/product_update.blade.php)

https://flareapp.io/share/A7EGbEmr

Comment: there seems a spelling mistake. it should be `product_name` not `porduct_name`. change according to your db column name.

Answer (score 1):

edit blade:

```
<form action="{{route('project.update', $project->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="group-form">
        <select  class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if($project->category_id) == $category->id) selected @endif>{{$category->category_name}}</option>       
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$project->product_name}}" 
             placeholder="Update Product Name" name="product_name" >  
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="select_file" >      
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" value="UPDATE"  name="Update" >  
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: After Applying your code   i am facing this error how to fit it ? record not showing on update page

Undefined property: stdClass::$porduct_name (View: /home/sigmadel/public_html/resources/views/admin/product_update.blade.php)


https://flareapp.io/share/A7EGbEmr

Comment: Share your model and table